# Angular 5 | Rendering progress bar using HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to add a [material progress-bar](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview#indeterminate) in my Angular 5 application using a HttpInterceptor.

Whenever there are any outstanding XHR requests, the progress bar should be visible and should be hidden/removed when there are no pending XHR requests.

Here is my `HttpInterceptor` implementation that keeps track of pending request count :-

```
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/publish';

@Injectable()
export class ProgressBatHttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  obs: Observable<number>; // PROBLEM: How to expose this as hot Obeservable ?
  private count = 0;

  constructor() {
    this.obs = Observable
      .create(observer => observer.next(this.count))
      .publish();
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.count++;   // increment the count here
    const observable = next.handle(req);
    observable.subscribe(() => {
    }, () => {
    }, () => {
      --this.count; // decrements the count.
    });
    return observable;
  }
}
```

**AppComponent** :-

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ProgressBatHttpInterceptorService} from './progress-bat-http-interceptor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(progress: ProgressBatHttpInterceptorService) {
    const obs = progress.obs;
    obs.subscribe(function (n) { // This never gets invoked.
      console.log(n);
    });
  }
}
```

The `ProgressBatHttpInterceptorService` is injected into `AppComponent`. In `AppComponent` constructor I am trying to subscribe to the count observable created in `ProgressBatHttpInterceptorService`.

I am planning to use the count Observable to conditionally show hide the progress bar.

**PROBLEM**

The .subscribe doesn't prints anything to console.

What's the correct way to create a hot observable for keeping track of outstanding request count ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subject

```
obs: Subject<number>=new Subject();
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
 Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.count++;   // increment the count here
const observable = next.handle(req).share(); // without share() , every call will be triggered twice
obs.next(this.count)
observable.subscribe(() => {
}, () => {
}, () => {
  --this.count; 
  obs.next(this.count)// decrements the count.
});
return observable;
}
```

Comment: Followed the Subject approach. Strangely the obs..asObservable().subscribe(c => console.log(c)); only works in 'ProgressBatHttpInterceptorService' & no subscription event recorded in AppComponent .  Any clue why is that happening ?

Comment: try change the subject to a static member, so only one instance of it is always available.

Comment: static worked !.  But why ! isn't ProgressBatHttpInterceptorService a singleton object in this scenario ?

Comment: It should be but i guess it's created by angular internally once you definited it properly. Interceptor probally not suppose to be injected. I will create a seperate service to fetch and redirect this event